# Updating a listView after button click - android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to put a list under 2 editTexts and 2 buttons. I am wondering how I can have the list be populated with strings after a button press.

Right now, I have an ArrayList and when the button is hit, it calls a method that uses data from the editTexts and adds values to the ArrayList. When I run it, it force closes. All I want to do is update the list with new values. Any idea are greatly appreciated.

Here is my code simplified a lot. This is where I am.

```
    public class test extends ListActivity{

    EditText currentText;   
    int current;
    EditText goalText;
    int goal;
            int[] xpTable = {1,200,30000,400000,500000};

    static ArrayList<String> objs = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);         


        Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myMethod();
            }

        });

    }

    public void myMethod(){

        currentText = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.xp);
        goalText = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.level);
        current = Integer.parseInt(currentText.getText().toString());
        goal = Integer.parseInt(goalText.getText().toString());
        int needed = xpTable[goal] - current;

        double laps = 0;
        double value1= 50.5;
        double value2= 100;



        laps = (needed/value1);
        if (laps % 1 != 0)
            laps = (laps - laps % 1) + 1;
        objs.add((int)laps + " value1");

        laps = (needed/value2);
        if (laps % 1 != 0)
            laps = (laps - laps % 1) + 1;
        objs.add((int)laps + " value2");


        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objs));
    }
}
```

Sorry for all my simple questions, This community is great for help.

Comment: A stack trace is necessary to help. Code would be useful, too.

Comment: What is the error in stack trace?

Comment: I added the code, I'm getting ACRA to get crash reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just re-set the adapter using your new value :

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, your_new_value));
```